# MySQL workbench cannot connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I use `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT'` of MySQL command on terminal; Check port is ‘0’ in terminal.
The version of MySQL is 8.0.13.

Comment: Do you have a specific error?

Comment: No、It just can't connect. Do you have a solution?